# How do I set the color of my host name in my bash prompt on macOS Monterey?

Tags: bash

I have the following line in my `.bash_profile` file to set up my custom bash prompt;

```
export PS1='\e[0;32m \[`[ $? = 0 ] && X=2 || X=1; tput setaf $X`\]\h\[`tput sgr0`\]:\w\$ \e[m'
```

but the color of the host name is a slightly darker green color compared to the rest of the prompt as shown. How can I set the whole bash prompt to be the same color of light green?

[image: Picture of my bash prompt]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. For general help with macOS you should post to [apple.se], [unix.se], or [su] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number `2` is dark green, try `10`(==8+2) :

```
export PS1='\e[0;32m \[`[ $? = 0 ] && X=10 || X=1; tput setaf $X`\]\h\[`tput sgr0`\]:\w\$ \e[m'
```

Comment: Check https://gist.github.com/dtmilano/4055d6df5b6e4ea87c5a72dc2d604193; you can show your colors